# Is it possible to integrate $\int (\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}) \frac{d z}{dt} dt$?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

> Is it possible to integrate the following indefinite integral analytically?  $$\int \left(\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right) \frac{d z(t)}{dt} dt$$

Where $f(x_1(t),x_2(t)):(x_1(t),x_2(t))\to \mathbb{R}^+$, and $x_1(t),x_2(t),z(t)$ are real continuous functions.

**Notes**

Initially I thought 
\begin{align}
&\int \left(\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right) \frac{d z(t)}{dt} dt\\
&=\int\left(\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right) dz(t)\\
&=\left(\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right) z(t)\\
\end{align}
Based on the separation of variables used to solve separable ODEs/PDEs. Obviously $\left(\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right) z(t)$ is incorrect as 
\begin{align}
 \left(\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)  z(t) \not= \left(\nabla f\cdot\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right) \frac{d z(t)}{dt}.\\
\end{align}

Is there any technique (maybe from calculus of variations?) that will allow me to integrate this integral?

**Context**

- If you need clarification feel free to ask.
- This is part of a much larger problem in trying to find a Lypunov function for a systems of ODEs (No $f$ is not a Lypunov function). I have reduced the problem of finding the Lypunov function to finding the integrals similar to the question above.